# Can't list any iptables rules with iptables -Lvn

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, fail2ban

I just installed fail2ban and when I wanted to check if ssh iptables jail is running. That is when I saw that `iptables -Lvn` list nothing. Iptables are running with custom script but I have no idea why no rules are listed. It just shows nothing, not even default policy This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
LOG_ALL="a"
# Known ports
HTTP_PORT="80"
HTTPS_PORT="443"
PROXY_PORT="3128"
PROXY="1.2.3.4"
NET="1.2.3.4/5"

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

###############################################################################

# Flush all rules
$IPT -F
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t mangle -F
$IPT -t raw -F

# Set Policies

$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT

###############################################################################

if [ "$1" = "stop" ]
then
        echo "Firewall completely flushed!  Now running with no firewall."
        exit 0
fi


# Logging of web access
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! -d $NET --dport $HTTP_PORT -j REJECT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! -d $NET --dport $HTTPS_PORT -j REJECT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! -d $PROXY --dport $PROXY_PORT -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

You should note that `-L` optionally takes the name of the chain to list, so by having `-Lvn` you ask for the chain `vn`. Try `-vnL` instead.

Comment: Thansk for reply, still nothing.  Is it possible that this feature is somehow disabled?

Comment: If it doesn't at least show three empty chains (INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT), or better, that there are 3 OUTPUT rules, then it may well be "disabled" in some way.

Comment: It does not. Literry nothing. Now even empty row.

Comment: Strange. How about `iptables-save` (if you have)? Also, check with `readlink -f $(which iptables)` for which program is actually used.

Comment: `iptables-save` shows all rules correctly. Readlink just list path to the iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It showed up that I am just stupied. I was launchin iptables -vnL in my home and there was the scrip for iptables so it keepet relaunching the same script. `/sbin/iptables -nvL` workes fine and shows all the rules